# No implementation for play.cache.SyncCacheApi annotated with @play.cache.NamedCache(value=options-cache) was bound

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.6, redis-cache

I am using play version 2.6.2 with play-redis from karelcemus version 2.0.1
https://github.com/KarelCemus/play-redis.
As per the documentation, I have disabled  play's default EhCacheModule and enabled `play.api.cache.redis.RedisCacheModule`
and bind named caches in application.conf below is code sample

```
play.cache.bindCaches = ["db-cache", "user-cache", "session-cache", "options-cache"]

play {
    modules {
        enabled += "play.api.cache.redis.RedisCacheModule"
        disabled += "play.api.cache.ehcache.EhCacheModule"
    }
}

play.cache.redis {
  bind-default = true
  instances {
    play {
      host:       localhost
      port:       6379
      prefix: default
    }

    options-cache{
      host:       localhost
      port:       6379
      prefix: options
    }
  }

}
```

for the implementation of cache I am using `play.cache.SyncCacheApi`

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import play.cache.NamedCache;
import play.cache.SyncCacheApi;


@Singleton
public class GeneralOptions extends BaseOptions {

    @Inject
    public GeneralOptions(@NamedCache("options-cache") SyncCacheApi cache) {
        super(cache);
    }
}
```

at compile time I am not getting error at run time below error is coming

```
No implementation for play.cache.SyncCacheApi annotated with @play.cache.NamedCache(value=options-cache) was bound.
  while locating play.cache.SyncCacheApi annotated with @play.cache.NamedCache(value=options-cache)
    for the 1st parameter of GeneralOptions.<init>(GeneralOptions.java:25)
  while locating GeneralOptions
```

so each and every class is throwing error who is using named-cache.Any clue what configuration I am missing ? . Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the author has used @Named instead of @NamedCache, and it is not written in neither play-redis-samples nor readme.

See here: https://github.com/KarelCemus/play-redis/issues/138

Comment: the author updated to `@NamedCache`: https://github.com/KarelCemus/play-redis/issues/138#issuecomment-355571209